# gcc: Undeclared variables in C, but they are declared

Tags: c, variables, gcc

Below is the first part of a C program I'm writing. gcc is throwing errors during compilation, however, to the effect that `set`, `p`, and `s1` are all undeclared, but they are declared. I'm having this problem with every function in this file, and I don't know what's going wrong. What do I need to do to resolve the problem?

The specific errors for this function:

```
a9.c: In function `makeaset':
a9.c:23: error: `set' undeclared (first use in this function)
a9.c:23: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
a9.c:23: error: for each function it appears in.)
a9.c:23: error: `p' undeclared (first use in this function)
a9.c:34: error: `s1' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

And the code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 32

struct set {
    char *data;
    int count;
};
typedef struct set set;

void makeaset(set **s1)
{
    int i;
    set *p;
    p = NULL;
    p = malloc(sizeof(set));
    if (p) {
        p->data = malloc(SIZE);
        if (p->data) {
            for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                p->data[i] = 0;
            p->count = 0;
        }
    }
    *s1 = p;
}
```

Comment: It appears the name-space of your types (`struct set`) is colliding with your variable name space (`set`).  Recommend different names for your compiler and for those reading your code.

Comment: As @chux said try `typedef struct set set_t;` and change the `set *p;` to be `set_t *p`

Comment: Just as a spot-check: this code compiles fine in gcc 4.2.1 . What version are you using?

Comment: 3.4.3 is the version installed on the server I'm using. Some updates would be nice. :) Thank you for the info!

Comment: The code snippet you posted is perfectly legal. It compiles without error for me using gcc 4.7.2, using `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra` (also `-std=c90` and `-std=c11`). Furthermore, your "snippet" is 26 lines, but you report error messages on line 34. Please (a) copy-and-paste your own snippet and compile it (I predict it will compile without error for you as well), and (b) post an *exact* self-contained source file that exhibits the error. The answer you've accepted is incorrect.

Comment: I used gcc 3.4.3 to compile it, and that is possibly the reason why the error exists. The second-to-last line is the one that triggers the `s1 undeclared` error; I trimmed some unnecessary code out between `typedef` and `makeaset()`. Running this exact snippet using your flags gives `Undefined symbol main first referenced in file /usr/sfw/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/3.4.3/crt1.o`.

Comment: @StevenH well... do you have a `main` function in this file? (likely not, as linker've said), so it works as it should. **But** it've compiled well, failing on linking phase. Which, to me, leads to the question - what was _yours_ compilation command that led to initially mentioned result?

Comment: @StevenH: Apparently the code you trimmed was not unnecessary. The `Undefined symbol main` error is unrelated to the errors you're asking about; it's a link-time error, and you won't get it if you compile with `gcc -c`. Not every source file requires a `main` function. We cannot help unless you show us code that actually produces the error you're asking about. (I've tried your code with versions of gcc from 2.8.1 to 4.8.1, and get no errors with any of them.) See http://sscce.org/

Comment: @chux those are separate 'namespaces', it's legal to have `typedef struct set set;`

Comment: @Matt McNabb  Agree it's legal to have `typedef struct set set`.  Yet "set" in the error message "error: `set' undeclared ..." is additionally unclear due to its use in 2 name-spaces.  Still recommend different names to improve the clarity of the error messages.  BTW: my first inclination was that the compiler was not compliant and so suggest the difference to clear the potential issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
struct set_struct {
    char *data;
    int count;
};
typedef struct set_struct set;
```

or something similar.

Comment: Is it? Used it times beyound counting. Not truly sure tho, need to check standard.

Comment: Beginning names with `_` or ending types with `_t` likely to run afoul of other standards.  Best to use meaningful names to the application.

Comment: This was exactly the problem, and it's now resolved. Thank you!

Comment: No, `typedef struct set set` is perfectly legal. There is no need for the struct tag and the typedef name to be distinct, since they're in different namespaces (not `namespace`s in the C++ sense).

Comment: Ye, just verified C99 standard, it explicitly states that structs/unions/enums and 'ordinary identifiers' (including typedefs) are separate. Is it a bug in specific compiler version or combination of some unobvious flags?

Comment: @keltar: I believe the problem is that the OP has not shown us the actual source that triggers the error messages. (The "snippet" is 26 lines long, but there's an error on line 34.)

Comment: I just replied as a comment to the original post, but I did provide all of the necessary code for this error.